# Excel: COUNT IF Column >= Another Column AND Equals x

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in Excel where multiple conditions are met.

I would like to create a statement where is says (apologies for the rudimentary example):

Count if Column A contains "Ball", Column B contains "Cat", and Column C's Date is >= Column D's Date

Comment: add sample data

Comment: As you have seen, us "imagining" your data will lead to wrong answers.  If you want correct answers you need to give us more information.  I realize you cannot share the actual table but you can put together a table using Ball and Cat and made up dates, that encompasses a full example of your actual data.  Please [edit] the post to include that as a mark down table and not a picture so we can copy paste.

Comment: Hi Scott the solution you originally posted was accurate.  It was a simple error on my part.  Thank you!

Comment: @user351293 then please consider marking my answer as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  And Please, next time take the time to create sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Use SUMPRODUCT and limit the ranges to the dataset

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Ball")*(B1:B10="Cat")*(C1:C10>=D1:D10))
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason that is not working :/

Comment: Then please mock up some data that we can use to test.  Because obviously I am imagining the data differently than you.

Comment: I think he means: `=SUMPRODUCT((isnumber(search("ball",A1:A10)))*(isnumber(search("cat",B1:B10)))*(C1:C10>=D1:D10))`

Comment: Simple formula error - this works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to be counted, or do you need a column to tell you whether the info is correct or not?

[image]

Comment: Questions in answers usually get downvoted as not answers.  This is borderline.  Please rephrase the answer and put the formula as text and not a photo so the OP can copy paste.